# ActiveAndroid lib issue

Tags: activeandroid

Getting error given below when adding this line of code in build.gradle. I am following given link here for activeandroid and given .jar at this link is also not compatible for java 8.
[https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Getting-started][1]

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

**Error:(39, 0)** Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.